# Using Angular library in the application causes error

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular12

I have simple angular library project named "test" with only one component displaying material icon. I have built it (ng build test)

My library module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [
    TestComponent
  ]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

I want to test this library in my angular application. I have added library in app.module.ts:

```
import {TestComponent} from '../../dist/test'
```

and

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TestComponent,
```

I'm using this component but unfortunatelly i get an error during **ng serve** command:

```
Error: ../../dist/test/lib/test.component.d.ts:3:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the dependency which declares TestComponent has not been processed correctly by ngcc.
```

Comment: You should import TestModule into AppModule, not TestComponent

Answer (score 0):

You should import TestModule into AppModule, not TestComponent

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to do this is to define an Angular `TestModule` in your library and have it include `TestComponent` in its declarations array. Then, you can import that module in your `AppModule`.

Otherwise, you'd have to include `TestComponent` directly in `AppModule` `declarations`, which beats the purpose of having a library.

Comment: My library looks exactly like you said. I modified my post so you could see how my library module looks like.

Comment: @Ellbar The library should "declare" and "export" the component. If you would use `ng g module ...` and `ng g module ...` to create them, it would create them correctly.

Comment: I have created library by angular CLI, nothing was created manually. TestComponent and TestModule is default component and module created by ng generate library test

Comment: @Ellbar the problem is that you are importing `TestComponent` in your `AppModule` instead of `TestModule`.